# How to disable bio-protection?

Tags: laptop, fingerprint

I have an Acer laptop, which has a fingerprint scanner. It's actually kind of a cool piece of technology, but I have no use for it. I only installed the driver so my device manager wouldn't report an unknown device.

Anyway, my problem is that it gives me the option to scan my fingerprint to log into my machine. I don't want that. I've disabled the biometric service from starting up and have removed all start-up entries. Once I'm logged in, there are no problems with the software; the fingerprint scanner does not work and no programs are associated with it. It's only on boot up at the log-in screen...

Is there a way to disable that log-in feature without uninstalling the program?

Comment: Go onto the screen where you can add fingerprints and then remove the green finger icon from the fingerlaunch part.

Comment: The fingerprint scanner and ThinkVantage Password Manager is one of the coolest things about my ThinkPad.  I never have to type in passwords for user accounts or websites.